# how to order by multiple columns in supabase?

Tags: psql, supabase, supabase-database

How can I order by publication, then by title in supabase?

This is wrong:

> ```
> .order('publicationDate', { ascending: false }, 'title', { ascending: true });
> ```

If I make them separate lines, the 2nd one overrides the first.

Comment: Reverse the order.  First line supa; last line pub.  Assuming enough have same title and pub...

Comment: what do you mean? the columns I'm trying to use in the order section are date and title.

Comment: Sorry two things, not 3, so just do it in separate lines. First line:do it by title. Second line: do it by date. Why it might work: when it reorders by date, there's no reason to re-order items that have the same date so it may preserve the title ordering for items that have same date.

Comment: ive already tried two separate .order lines. it doesnt work.

Comment: sorry Abel - you are right. it does work. i don't know why it didnt on the previous attempt. For others, two separate .order lines will order in two cascading flows. I apologise to you Abel. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

According to the comment in the source code of [@supabase/postgres-js package](https://github.com/supabase/postgrest-js/blob/master/src/PostgrestTransformBuilder.ts)
the only way to order by multiple columns is by using `.order` method multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

I sort of just wrote this without testing it, so it might not work (syntax), but let me know what happens!

**Some Context:**

In Supabase, which uses PostgREST behind the scenes, when you want to order by multiple columns, you should use an array.

The .order() function enables users to order by multiple columns by supplying an array of columns and, optionally, an array of corresponding ordering directions.

**Now the code:**

```js
.order([{ column: 'publicationDate', order: 'desc' }, { column: 'title', order: 'asc' }])
```

So, your full Supabase query might look something like this:

```js
supabase
  .from('yourTableName')
  .select('*')
  .order([{ column: 'publicationDate', order: 'desc' }, { column: 'title', order: 'asc' }])
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.order([{ column: 'publicationDate', ascending: false }, { column: 'title', ascending: true }])
```

This code will first order your results by `publicationDate` in descending order (most recent first) and then, for items with the same publication date, it will further order them by `title` in ascending order (alphabetical order). This should give you the desired ordering for your Supabase results.